# Three.js - scale cylinder from point

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to increase the scale of a cylinder on the Y-axis from a specific point.

As instead of the cylinder growing from its origin up and down to the new scale, growing from the top upwards/downwards only like a bar chart.

Current code :

```
function animate() {
    render();
    cylinder.scale.y += 0.1;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a intermediary `Object3D` to achieve this:

```
var cylinder = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( cylinder );

var cylinderMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry.material);
cylinder.add(cylinderMesh);

cylinderMesh.position.y = 2; // move pivot up
cylinder.scale.y += 0.1;
```