# how to change A-Frame a-box height without changing y-position of a-box base?

Tags: aframe

this is what I see from inside the Vive, in VR mode:

[image]

how can I scale the bar height while leaving the y-position of the bar fixed?

`demo` https://github.com/micahstubbs/aframe-ui-widgets/blob/three-knobs-example/examples/three-knobs/index.html#L55

an image of my code, from the `demo` link
[image]

the

`targetEntity.setAttribute('position', {
        y: 0.5
      });`

bit is an earlier attempt to fix the y-position of the base of the bar :sweat-smile:

Comment: I think this THREE answer will put you on the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463244/three-js-scale-cylinder-from-point

Answer (score 0):

If you could, I think changing the position is a viable solution.

You could apply a `translate` to the geometry: (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1364):

```
el.getObject3D('mesh').geometry.translate(0, height / 2, 0);
```

A-Frame's geometry component used to have this as a property, but we removed it. There's a `pivot` too now that wraps the whole object in a group to apply the offset (mileage may vary): https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/extras/components/pivot.js

Comment: thanks! investigating, will report back.  tried changing the y-position, but need to figure out right  offset or scaling to apply 